# How to properly use multiple DataTables in one vanilla Winform Chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I am trying to visualize data from multiple Tables from a DataSet in vanilla Winform Chart using c#.

I have a DataSet with two tables.

`Tables[0]` has information about monthly plan usage.

`Tables[1]` contains monthly pack usage.

The chart has 4 Series:

- 2 series bind to `Table[0]` and use column "Start_date" for XValueMember and column "Document_Used" for Y.
- 2 series bind to `Table[1]` and use column "Start_date" for XValueMember and column "Document_Used" for Y.

This is my code so far:

```
            chart_usage.DataSource = chart_ds;

            Series used_doc = chart_usage.Series.Add("Plan Usage");
            used_doc.XValueMember = chart_ds.Tables[0].Columns[6].ColumnName;
            used_doc.YValueMembers = chart_ds.Tables[0].Columns[1].ColumnName;
            used_doc.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
            used_doc.Color = Color.Red;

            Series allow_doc = chart_usage.Series.Add("Monthly Allowed documents");
            allow_doc.XValueMember = chart_ds.Tables[0].Columns[6].ColumnName;
            allow_doc.YValueMembers = chart_ds.Tables[0].Columns[2].ColumnName;
            allow_doc.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            allow_doc.BorderWidth = 5;
            allow_doc.Color = Color.DarkRed;

            Series pack_used_doc = chart_usage.Series.Add("Pack Usage");
            pack_used_doc.XValueMember = chart_ds.Tables[1].Columns[6].ColumnName;
            pack_used_doc.YValueMembers = chart_ds.Tables[1].Columns[1].ColumnName;
            pack_used_doc.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
            pack_used_doc.Color = Color.Blue;

            Series pack_allow_doc = chart_usage.Series.Add("Annual Allowed Usage");
            pack_allow_doc.XValueMember = chart_ds.Tables[1].Columns[6].ColumnName;
            pack_allow_doc.YValueMembers = chart_ds.Tables[1].Columns[2].ColumnName;
            pack_allow_doc.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            pack_allow_doc.BorderWidth = 5;
            pack_allow_doc.Color = Color.DarkBlue;
```

The problem is:

the chart shows all the series but seems only using `Tables[0]` data.

[My chart screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4Q1V.png)

Notes:

- The data are coming from 2 database queries each returning a DataTable and later combined to one DataSet(chart_ds).
- I don't want to bind the chart to a database, as the database connection can be different.

Thank you in advance

Comment: There are many ways to bind a chart. Try binding not the chart as a whole but each series.points separately! - For an overview of Binding Data to Series (Chart Controls) see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd456766%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)!

Comment: @Taw thanks. I'll try it out.